# How to call a management.call_command in remote serve with Django?

Tags: python, django, ldap

I have a job script in Python that call a command to update AD users. When I run this command in my local machine, it works fine. But in our Remote Server, with Linux and Apache, the same script doesn't work and give me a error: "Unknown command: 'ldap_sync_users'... I tried to use other common commands like migrate (just to test) and it gives the same problem...

This is the command that I'm trying to run and works fine in my local:

```
# https://github.com/etianen/django-python3-ldap   
management.call_command('ldap_sync_users')
```

I'm using Python 3.6, Django 2.0.4. In localserver I'm using virtualenv and in remote server Apache 2. What I'm doing wrong? Someone can help me?

view.py

```
...
from apps.iumob.utilities import sync_hr_with_ldap

def cron_job_to_sync(request):
    print(request.GET.get('token'))
    if request.GET.get('token') == "mytoken":
        if sync_hr_with_ldap() is True:
            return HttpResponse("Records synchronization finished.")
        else:
            return HttpResponse("Records synchronization finished with errors.")
    else:
        return HttpResponse("Access forbidden.")
```

utilities.py:

```
from django.core import management

def sync_hr_with_ldap():
"""
This method will be called to synchronize AD users and workers.
If some worker that have a user and he was fired, it will check all users and, if it is still active,
it will save in database this record. Every time that the user is deactivate from AD,
this record will also be updated.
"""

# This method call a library that call LDAP and check all users, inactivating if necessary
# https://github.com/etianen/django-python3-ldap
management.call_command('ldap_sync_users')`
```

**Traceback**

```
Environment:


Request Method: GET
Request URL: myurl.../pt-br/iumob/cron-job-sync?token=sometoken

Django Version: 2.0.3
Python Version: 3.5.2
Installed Applications:
['apps.iumob.apps.IumobConfig',
 'apps.hrmob.apps.HrmobConfig',
 'apps.cimob.apps.CimobConfig',
 'apps.users.apps.UsersConfig',
 'django.contrib.admin',
 'django.contrib.auth',
 'django.contrib.contenttypes',
 'django.contrib.sessions',
 'django.contrib.messages',
 'django.contrib.staticfiles',
 'django_python3_ldap',
 'rest_framework',
 'rest_framework.authtoken']
Installed Middleware:
['django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.locale.LocaleMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware']



Traceback:

File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py" in call_command
  102.             app_name = get_commands()[command_name]

During handling of the above exception ('ldap_sync_users'), another exception occurred:

File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/django/core/handlers/exception.py" in inner
  35.             response = get_response(request)

File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py" in _get_response
  128.                 response = self.process_exception_by_middleware(e, request)

File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py" in _get_response
  126.                 response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)

File "/var/www/marcomob/apps/iumob/views.py" in cron_job_to_sync
  43.         if sync_hr_with_ldap() is True:

File "/var/www/marcomob/apps/iumob/utilities.py" in sync_hr_with_ldap
  19.     management.call_command('ldap_sync_users')

File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py" in call_command
  104.             raise CommandError("Unknown command: %r" % command_name)

Exception Type: CommandError at /pt-br/iumob/cron-job-sync
Exception Value: Unknown command: 'ldap_sync_users'
```

Comment: Detail: when I try to execute the same command by ssh in remote serve all works fine... Just not in the python script.

    python manage.py ldap_sync_users

Comment: Please show a minimal script that reproduces the problem. It sounds as if `django-python3-ldap` is not in `INSTALLED_APPS` when it fails - perhaps you are not configuring the settings correctly.

Comment: Thanks Alasdair. But the module is in INSTALLED_APPS. I can login with LDAP and as I commented before, when I try to execute python manage.py ldap_sync_users directly at the promt (even in remote server), it works fine. Just the python script is not recognizing this command and just in the remote server. I will add the full script in the question.

Comment: It's still not clear to me what's going on. If you're calling that from a view, then show the view. The full traceback might help as well.

Comment: Traceback added.

Comment: I can't spot any issues in the code you have posted (apart from indentation). I'm surprised that the error error occurs inside the `process_exception_by_middleware`, but I can't see why that's happening from the code you have posted. I think you're going to have to step through the code with a debugger, to try to figure out why `get_commands()` isn't finding the commands.

Comment: Thank you anyway. I will continue to test and debug as you suggested.